# EJB Singleton Issues

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, singleton, ejb

I'm having issues with EJB 3.1 singletons. I created a simple project to see if I could even get them to instantiate correctly, however, due to a long Glassfish 3.1.2.2 exception, it looks like I'm doing starting something off wrong.

I'm using maven to compile this into a WAR (with no web.xml descriptor). I'm using jax-rs w/ Jersey to handle rest calls.

It looks like I can't instantiate SingletonA (it fails when I try to deploy the app). SingletonB isn't injected/created by the time the method marked with @PostConstruct is called.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
<artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>myproject</name>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is RestApp

```
package main;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/rest/")
public class RestApp extends Application {
}
```

Here is my SingletonA

```
package main;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.DependsOn;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.inject.Inject;


@Singleton
@Startup
@DependsOn("SingletonB")
public class SingletonA {
    @Inject SingletonB sb;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        System.out.println("\n\n>In SingletonA's startup\n");
        sb.doSomethingCool();
    }

    public String test()
    {
        return sb.getIt();
    }
}
```

Here is SingletonB

```
package main;

import javax.ejb.Singleton;


@Singleton
public class SingletonB {
    public void doSomethingCool()
    {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n>>Singleton B did something cool!\n\n\n");
    }

    public String getIt()
    {
        return "my string";
    }
}
```

Rest Service:

```
package main;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("")
@Stateless
public class RestSvc {
    @Inject SingletonA sa;

    @Path("/get")
    @GET
    public String asdf()
    {
        return sa.test();
    }
}
```

And finally here's the stacktrace from the server:

```
[#|2012-12-07T10:21:42.934-0700|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.tools.admin.org.glassfish.deployment.admin|_ThreadID=156;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Exception while loading the app : javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton SingletonA
javax.ejb.CreateException: Initialization failed for Singleton SingletonA
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:547)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.access$100(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:79)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer$SingletonContextFactory.create(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:719)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.instantiateSingletonInstance(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:451)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:216)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.initializeSingleton(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.SingletonLifeCycleManager.doStartup(SingletonLifeCycleManager.java:155)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:301)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:461)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:214)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:207)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:148)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:134)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:182)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:147)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:148)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at main.SingletonA.init(SingletonA.java:20)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.BeanCallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:1009)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:65)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInvocationContext.proceed(CallbackInvocationContext.java:113)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCallback(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:138)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.init(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:964)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.CallbackChainImpl.invokeNext(CallbackChainImpl.java:65)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:393)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:376)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.AbstractSingletonContainer.createSingletonEJB(AbstractSingletonContainer.java:538)
        ... 62 more
|#]
```

Comment: Try adding a default constructor to your EJB. I had a similar problem recently where it helped thought you would say the compiler generates a default constructor when no constructor is supplied.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added default public constructors to the singletons and changed all of the \@Inject annotation to \@EJB. I can deploy my application now, however, in the rest application - it won't inject SingletonA. I get a NullPointerException in the /get rest call.

Answer (score 1):

If your EJBs are injected using @EJB, but are not using @Inject, it probably means you forgot to add a `beans.xml` file (even empty), in the WEB-INF directory. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html.

Comment: Interesting. I've heard using Inject is the way to go with EE 6 (I was going between Inject/EJB to see if maybe the exception would provide something useful). When I try using Inject, I get an NPE in my rest service (SingletonA is null). Do you know if I need another annotation for that singleton? I see the message when I deploy in server.log "In SingletonA's Startup", but for some reason CDI doesn't want to inject that instance.

Comment: And have you put a beans.xml file in WEB-INF?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry - I didn't see you said that. Is there an example of what the beans.xml file looks like? Everything I've seen is for the Spring framework (would the file be the same for EE6?). I'd definitely like to give this a try as using the glassfish dependencies seems a little hackish.

Comment: It can be completely empty if you don't do anything fancy like declaring interceptor bindings, etc. But it serves as an indicator for the container that the web app contains CDI beans and that its classes should thus be scanned for CDI annotations and that beans should be created and injected.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the pom dependencies. I couldn't give anything more than speculation why this fixed it, but it did. If someone knows why this worked, please leave a comment why.

Here's my new POM file (I changed the dependencies. Removed the javaee-api v6 and used glassfish javax.ejb instead.

There is no web.xml or beans.xml in this project (I had read that with EE 6, these files were optional)

I couldn't use @Inject anymore, so all my injections were changed to @EJB. With this I was able to successfully instantiate both singletons, and inject them without issue.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MyGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>myartifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myproject</name>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ejb</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: the beans.xml file is not optional if you want CDI to be used. Read the link I sent in my answer.